# How to query location "within" in OrientDB 2.2.x Spatial Module in Java?

Tags: java, geospatial, orientdb, spatial, orientdb2.2

I'mm trying to implement OrientDB Spatial Module and need some help on coding it in Java.

How do I do the equivalent query in Java:

```
select *,ST_Distance_Sphere(location,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12.4696635 41.8894657)')) as distance from Points where ST_Distance_Sphere(location,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12.4696635 41.8894657)')) < 200 order by distance
```

[Reference](http://orientdb.com/spatial-module-orientdb-2-2/)

Thanks!

Comment: There is no equivalent in java. You should execute a command/query
How would you run this in java?

Comment: I thought there is some way to build the query and execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to use OSQL:

```
    List<ODocument> execute = db.query(new OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument>(
    "select   *,ST_Distance_Sphere(location,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12.4696635 41.8894657)')) as distance from Points where ST_Distance_Sphere (location,ST_GeomFromText('POINT(12.4696635 41.8894657)')) < 200 order by distance"));
```

Does it helps?